# Can I join multiple tables to one?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I need two tables linked together but with mulitple columns on one table linked to only one column on another.

So I have A table "Opportunities" Which has an account ID, contact ID, and lead ID (all optional on the table, but must have at least one of those fields not be null. So an opportunity record has to have at least one of those ID columns populated with data)

The other table is an Activities table which can be linked to an Account, Contact, or Lead using the regardingobjectid column.  So essentially I would need something like this.

Opportunities[accountid] = Activities[regardingobjectid]
OR
Opportunities[contactid] = Activities[regardingobjectid]
OR
Opportunities[leadid] = Activities[regardingobjectid]

Any ideas?

Comment: Try show sample table with the expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using 'Merge Queries As New' under 'Merge Queries' in Home Tab.
Load Opportunities, Activities tables into Power Query and select columns as mentioned in images and you will get desired results.

[image: Merge_step1]

[image: Merge_step2]

[image: Merge_step3]

[image: Merge_step4]